# How to disable snap options in Win10?

Tags: windows-10

When you snap a Window to the left half or right half or your screen by pressing Win+[Left|Right], Win10 suggests some open apps that you can pin in the other half.

This steals my keyboard focus away from the app I was trying to work in. How do I disable this "feature"?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tenforums created a guide](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4343-aero-snap-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) how to do this. Open the settings app, go to `system -> multitasking` and turn off the setting `Arrange windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or corners of the screen`

[image]

Comment: It's actually just "When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it" that I want to turn off, but you helped me find it, so thanks!

Comment: Only turn off  3rd option would be fine.