# How do I stop the "also snap" screen on Win 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Given I am using windows 10

When I select a window

And I hit <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Then the window snaps to the left half of the screen

[image: screenshot of windows 10 after snapping]

And the right half of the screen (annoyingly) shows other windows that are available to snap to that half, which I call the "also snap" screen.

And then I press escape or something and it goes away -- unless I accidentally forget about it and press some other buttons in which case it snaps some random process to that half of the screen, which is annoying.

How can I disable the "also snap" feature?

jw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable snap options in Win10?](https://superuser.com/questions/973143/how-to-disable-snap-options-in-win10)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable Snap-Assist by going into Settings -> System -> Mustitasking and disabling `When I snap a window show what I can snap next to it`

[image]

Comment: I can't tell you how long I've been trying to figure that out. Thank you!

Comment: @MustModify you're welcome!