# How do I snap a window on side of screen without having to select the other half?

Tags: windows-10

*Using right-hand-side of screen and left-hand-side of screen to better illustrate the question. Of course, it works identically in reverse as well.*

On Windows 10 (I believe since Windows 7), you can snap a window to the right hand side of the screen by dragging it to the right edge. In doing so, it occupies exactly half the screen, and fills top-to-bottom.

However, when there are other windows open - if these aren't already snapped to the left hand side of the screen - you are given a selection of the various windows you have open. Selecting one then fills the left hand side  with this window.

Often, I find I want to have many small windows open for various tasks, but stick something else onto the right hand side without disrupting the other window's layouts.

**Is it possible to disable this selection, so that dragging a window to the right hand side still snaps, but doesn't then prompt me to fill the left side?**

Comment: I would say that you cannot do this. If you snap one window to the right, then underlying windows show up on the left. If you then click on the snapped window, it is now full screen where it was not before. So there are several things going on in a Snap operation and I do not think you can leave other windows undisturbed.

Answer (score 14):

As answered here: https://superuser.com/a/1097166/159599 ,

"You can disable Snap-Assist by going into Settings -> System -> Mustitasking and disabling *When I snap a window show what I can snap next to it*".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is away to disable this function without editing a registry key, and I don't even know if you can do it that way.

However, if you have multiple widows sized multiple ways when you snap something to a side manually or with shortcuts (widow key + arrow direction) and are prompted to pick the second window you can just hit the escape key and all other windows will stay the same as before you snapped.